# AWS - I need to download a file from Amazon S3 into Android APP and the URL have to be hidden

Tags: android, file, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I have to download a file from Amazon S3 to Android APP via Servlet and I have to hide the URL.
Is there a solution to download a file without Android App know the path?

[image]

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need a special layer - so called "API" displayed as Servlet on the picture. Your app passes some param like id of a picture to an API method and API returns a picture in response. Its up to API how it will dl the image from AWS but the app will never know the real url. API is a web-service, a kind of web-site which could be seen only programmatically using HTTP-requests and is a job for web-developers.
I'm not much of a web developer so I can't explain how to develop it using ElasticBeanstalk or anything else. However the main idea is that you have to assign some unique id to every file you upload to amazon. Every unique id must be related (correspond) to a particular file's url. These relations must be known to your API/server/backend only (for instance - url "http:/amazon.com/file01" will be stored as a file with id 1 and so on). Your android app should know only the id of a file (for instance - app requests a list of files from your API and gets a JSON array of available files like "`{files:[{id:1,name:"file01"},{id:2,name:"file02"},{id:3,name:"file03"}...]}`). So when app requests a file it "says" to API only the id (1 or 2 or 3 showing to user only a file name), the server then looks for an url of that file matching given id, downloads it and sends it to your app or creates a buffer stream so server sends received data from amazon to app and app "thinks" that file comes from your API/server (but it will be downloaded from amazon in real). Your API/server should be something like a proxy server.
 Also you could use FireBase Real DataBase for your needs, like to store id<->url relations there.

Comment: Many thanks!
I didn't understand some points:
- my target is to hide the real path, how can i use this API in the servlet  that is on ElasticBeanstalk?
- how you explained me the procedure with id as param, could you show my an example?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not much of web-developer so I can't explain how to develop it using ElasticBeanstalk.